# My Input from scanf() isn't stored

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
  int pq1, pq2;
  float ptq;

  ptq = pq1 + pq2;

  printf ("\t-Prelims-\n");
  printf ("Grade from Quiz #1?\n");
  printf ("Grade from Quiz #2?\n");

  gotoxy (36, 4);
  scanf ("%d", &pq1);
  gotoxy (36, 5);
  scanf ("%d", &pq2);

  printf ("Your grades from prelims is %.2f", &ptq);

  return 0;
}
```

My input in scanf doesn't save and the grades in prelims always display 0.00 and didn't compute.

pls help. I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: Don't pass the address of `ptq` in the `printf` call. See other answers that you must calculate the result _after_ reading the input.

Comment: Read carefully [documentation of `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). You should use its return count. See also [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is a procedural language, so the lines execute one after the other. You have to use the values after you read them in

```
int main ()
{
  int pq1, pq2;
  float ptq;

  ptq = pq1 + pq2; // this is undefined as you have not set a value for pq1, pq2

  printf ("\t-Prelims-\n");
  printf ("Grade from Quiz #1?\n");
  printf ("Grade from Quiz #2?\n");

  gotoxy (36, 4);
  scanf ("%d", &pq1);
  gotoxy (36, 5);
  scanf ("%d", &pq2);

  // now you have values for pq1 and pq2, so this is where you should be using them

  printf ("Your grades from prelims is %.2f", &ptq); // here you should be using the value of ptq not its address, as we are outputting it not asking the function to fill it in.

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you declare variables;

`int pq1, pq2;`

then you try to count the sum

`ptq = pq1 + pq2;`

And then you read user input. It is a little bit out of order.

Try to sum after scanning

```
ptq = pq1 + pq2;
printf ("Your grades from prelims is %.2f", ptq);
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare `pq1` and `pq2` without specifying their value. Then you define `ptq = pq1 + pq2` so `ptq` doesn't really store any wanted value. After using `scanf()` your `pq1` and `pq2` change but `ptq` doesn't.

You need to calculate your `ptq` after `scanf()`:

```
ptq = pq1 + pq2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the numbers before even getting it from user.

```
  ptq = pq1 + pq2;
```

Move the above line after scanf.

```
  gotoxy (36, 4);
  scanf ("%d", &pq1);
  gotoxy (36, 5);
  scanf ("%d", &pq2);

      ptq = pq1 + pq2;
```